# Is there a minimum size for a galaxy to have spiral arms?

Tags: galaxy, size, spiral-arms

Is there a minimum size or mass for a galaxy to present spiral arms? I don't remember many small galaxies with spiral arms.

Does the mechanism responsible for producing spiral arms no longer hold if the galaxy is too small?

Comment: related https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/how-small-can-a-spiral-galaxy-be?r=SearchResults&s=1|35.8401 and https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18611/why-do-galaxies-have-arms?rq=1